# How do you use externally defined materials in a URDF.Xacro file?

Tags: rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How do you apply a material definition located in an external udrf.xacro file?

I have a materials.urdf.xacro file like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<robot>
  <material name="black">
    <color rgba="0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0"/>
  </material>
 
  <material name="blue">
    <color rgba="0.0 0.0 0.8 1.0"/>
  </material>
 
  <material name="green">
    <color rgba="0.0 0.8 0.0 1.0"/>
  </material>
 
  <material name="gray">
    <color rgba="0.7 0.7 0.7 1.0"/>
  </material>
 
  <material name="darkgray">
    <color rgba="0.3 0.3 0.3 1.0"/>
  </material>
 
  <material name="red">
    <color rgba="0.8 0.0 0.0 1.0"/>
  </material>
 
  <material name="white">
    <color rgba="1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0"/>
  </material>
 
  <material name="yellow">
    <color rgba="0.8 0.8 0.0 1.0"/>
  </material>
</robot>
```

and I'm trying to include and use these materials like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<robot name="myrobot"
    xmlns:xacro="http://www.ros.org/wiki/xacro">
    <xacro:include filename="$(find myrobot_description)/urdf/materials.urdf.xacro" />
    <link name="torso">
        <visual>
            <geometry>
                <box size="1 1 1" />
            </geometry>
            <material name="red"/>
        </visual>
        <xacro:default_inertial mass="1"/>
    </link>
</robot>
```

However, when I run:

```
roslaunch urdf_tutorial xacrodisplay.launch model:='$(find myrobot_description)/urdf/myrobot.urdf.xacro'
```

Rviz renders the box as white and not red. Why is that?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/207947/how-do-you-use-externally-defined-materials-in-a-urdf.xacro-file?/) by [Cerin](https://answers.ros.org/users/2186/cerin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 940 on 2015-04-26

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

From [the tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/action/subscribe/urdf/Tutorials/Building%20a%20Visual%20Robot%20Model%20with%20URDF%20from%20Scratch?action=subscribe#Origins) you see:

```
If a TF frame does not exist for a given URDF link, then it will be placed at the origin in white.
```

In your case, changing link name from "torso" to "base_link" should do the work.

UPDATE: @Dlu is right. Although `torso` might not be available in the fixed frame pulldown menu, you can manually type in `torso`.

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2015-04-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Cerin](https://answers.ros.org/users/2186/cerin/) on 2015-04-26**:
Unfortunately, that tutorial never explains what a "TF frame" is, so that note doesn't help.

**Comment by [Cerin](https://answers.ros.org/users/2186/cerin/) on 2015-04-26**:
Although I don't understand why, this fixes it. I wish there was a more intuitive solution though.

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2015-04-27**:
Might be a good call: URDF tutorial requires you to have finished TF tutorials. I [opened a ticket](https://github.com/ros/geometry/issues/94).